# Getting Pre-Populated Tags Via JQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I'm using this "bootstrap-tags" jquery plugin (https://github.com/maxwells/bootstrap-tags) to add a simple tagging interface to a web app I'm working on. In the happy path, I can get the plugin to work fine, however I actually need to pull the tags shown on page load from a MySQL DB. The code I have now is:

```
$.get("getCurrentTags.php", 
    {"id": id] }, 
    function(data) { 
        $('#my-tag-list').tags({
              tagData: data,
              bootstrapVersion: "2"
        });
    }
);
```

Doing this actually gives me the following error in the Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '12' in ["Civil War"]
```

I **think this is more of a general problem** and has something to do with how 'data' is formatted going into my callback function, **especially since it works if I manually type something like**

```
tagData: ["Civil War"]
```

but I just can't figure out what it is exactly.

For thoroughness, my 'getCurrentTags.php' looks like this:

```
include('db.php');
$oid = $_GET['id'];

$currentTags = array();
$currentTagsQuery = mysql_query("SELECT tag_name 
    FROM t_tag t
    JOIN t_object_tag ot ON ot.tag_id = t.tag_id
    WHERE ot.id = {$oid};")
or die(mysql_error());

while($tag = mysql_fetch_assoc($currentTagsQuery))
{
    $currentTags[] = $tag['tag_name'];
}

echo json_encode($currentTags);
```

I've been stuck on this for most of the day today and am entirely stumped; any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: One observation is that you are sending json as a response from your php but not parsing it in the JavaScript. Have you tried using `$.getJSON` instead?

Comment: @scartz - I have, but then 'data' is an array which seems even further from what I want unless I'm misunderstanding something (very possible).

Comment: an array is what you want - I've posted a reply below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your example locally, and it performs as expected using:

```
 $.getJSON("getCurrentTags.php", {"id": id}, function(data) {
   $('#my-tag-list').tags({
     tagData: data,
     bootstrapVersion: "2"
   });
 });
```

Another thing to note is your server side code is vulnerable to SQL injection as you're inserting an unsanitized value directly into your SQL statement.  If it is available to you, I would recommend you use PDO. In the case of your example, my server side code looked like this:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

$stmt = $db->prepare(
 "SELECT tag_name 
  FROM t_tag t
  JOIN t_object_tag ot ON ot.tag_id = t.tag_id
  WHERE ot.id =  :id"
);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$currentTags = array();

foreach($result as $row) {
  $currentTags[] = $row['tag_name'];
}

echo json_encode($currentTags);
```

A good introduction to PDO can be found [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I really thought I'd attempted to use .getJSON previously and it hadn't worked, but lo-and-behold, following your example it does now! The help is much appreciated and I'll definitely look into updating the MySQL interacting portions to PDO.